# If $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$ with $|a-b|\le\delta$, does $a\ge \delta + b$ or $a\ge -\delta + b$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, real-numbers

Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$ be such that there exists $\delta >0, \delta\sim 0$ such that $|a-b|\le\delta$.

I would like to prove that an estimate like (I mean up to some positive constant)
$$a\ge \delta + b \quad\text{ or }\quad a\ge -\delta + b$$
holds true.

I was thinking something like
$$a \ge |b- |a-b||\ge |b-\delta|.$$

Could someone please help me with that?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}_+^*$?

Comment: If $a \geq \delta +b$ then $a-b \geq \delta > 0$ and so $|a-b| \geq \delta$, so if you have $|a-b|<\delta$ this is never going to happen.

Comment: @Leo, it denotes all the real numbers strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: @Randall thank you for the comment. Not even $a\ge -\delta +b$ could happen?

Comment: $|a - b| \leq \delta \implies a \in [b-\delta, b+ \delta]$ and $b \in [a- \delta, a + \delta]$.

Comment: $|a-b| \leq \delta$ means that $a-\delta \leq b \leq a+\delta$.  Use this to derive what you need.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments, that's clear to me now.